# Explode out polars column of list items horizontally to new columns

Tags: python-3.x, python-polars

Is there a polars native way to explode out a column of lists horizontally?

e.g. go from this:

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "letters": ["a", "a", "b", "c"],
        "numbers": [[1, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]],
    }
)
```

To this?

```
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "letters": ["a", "a", "b", "c"],
        "numbers_a": [1, 2, 4, 6],
        "numbers_b": [1, 3, 5, 7]
    }
)
```

I am aware of the `.explode()` method but afaik this is only possible to use vertically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this.

### struct/unnest

The easiest is to [`.list.to_struct`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.list.to_struct.html#polars.Expr.list.to_struct) and then [`unnest`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.unnest.html#polars.DataFrame.unnest)

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

(
    df
    .with_columns(
        pl.col('numbers').list.to_struct(
            fields=lambda idx: f"numbers_{ascii_lowercase[idx]}",
            n_field_strategy='max_width'
            )
        )
    .unnest('numbers')
)
```

### get

```
from string import ascii_lowercase
max_width=df['numbers'].list.len().max()
(
    df
    .select(
        pl.exclude('numbers'), 
        *[pl.col('numbers').list.get(x).alias(f"numbers_{ascii_lowercase[x]}") 
          for x in range(max_width)]
        )
    )
```

In either case you're going to get:

```
shape: (4, 3)
┌─────────┬───────────┬───────────┐
│ letters ┆ numbers_a ┆ numbers_b │
│ ---     ┆ ---       ┆ ---       │
│ str     ┆ i64       ┆ i64       │
╞═════════╪═══════════╪═══════════╡
│ a       ┆ 1         ┆ 1         │
│ a       ┆ 2         ┆ 3         │
│ b       ┆ 4         ┆ 5         │
│ c       ┆ 6         ┆ 7         │
└─────────┴───────────┴───────────┘
```

In the former case you can more easily chain the methods but the second case relies on first determining the `max_width` which is less flexible. The second method *might* be more performant but I don't really know for sure so it's worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

To those who cannot use the .list() method like myself,

```
# get timestamps as list
numbers_col= list(df['numbers'])

# transpose this
numbers_col = list(map(list, zip(*numbers_col)))

# add the columns back in
df = df.with_columns(
    pl.Series(name='numbers_a', values=numbers_col[0]),
    pl.Series(name='numbers_b', values=numbers_col[1]),
)
```

My question was is there any polars native way, so I will accept the other answer.

Comment: how is it that you "cannot use the .list() method"? Do you have an old version? If so, and also assuming there's a really good reason why you can't upgrade to latest, replace `.list` for `.arr`.

Comment: Code base is unfortunately frozen to 0.17.10 at the moment, I could update although it might take me a while though! Thanks for your help

Comment: Did `arr()` not exist back then either?